# Is there a way to clear the Error List window of custom errors?

Tags: visual-studio, build, error-list

I use several custom tools during the build process, mostly code generators for service references, T4 templating, and the like.

When these produce errors or warnings, they show up in the **Error List** window as expected. However, if I do a build, rebuild, or clean of some portion of the solution that does not touch upon the errors produced previously (say I'm *not* building a project that has a service reference import failure), the old list is still displayed.

Is there a way to fix that: Tool, plugin, build action, anything? I don't want to ignore the errors/warnings, only want the relevant ones to show based on what I'm doing. If not I guess this would be a request for the VS team.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Closing and re-opening the project is the only way to clear the list. From what I can tell and the research I've done, the error/warnings window is like a session log for the project. Once you close the project the log is deleted.

Comment: I can't believe more than 10 years after this problem is not fixed by Microsoft. I encounter it very oftenly with VS2022, and the only working solution is to close Visual Studio, or at least the solution. It's a PITA with big solutions and plugins like Resharper that makes any huge project very long to load.

Answer (score 30):

Cleaning the solution does it as well. 
[image: Clear the error list in Visual Studio]

Comment: it is for VS2012 and onwards

Comment: @KayZed It's working for VS2015. Just do "Clean Solution".

Comment: Works in VS2010 as well, for me.

Comment: @tom_mai78101 "The thing doesn't work for me." "Sure it does, just do it" Real helpful comment there

Comment: @ParkerKemp Got a screenshot showing why you can't remove error logs  after a "Clean Solution"? Unless, your error messages involves LNK errors, IntelliSense errors, or some VS configuration errors, cleaning your solutions is a quick way of removing the error logs.

Comment: @tom_mai78101 I'm not the one who was having the issue a year ago. I just happened across this post and thought your response was obtuse.

Comment: @ParkerKemp Oh I see. No it's not obtuse. It's indeed an actual solution. It was fixed in Update 2, and now we're at VS2015 Update 3.

Comment: Whatever the cause (I'm assuming design bugs), there are a fair number of errors that get "stuck" in the list for the entire session, even once the issue has been resolved. It's simply not correct to say that "Clean Solution" always works. It's a good place to start, but in my experience, only exiting and re-opening the solution works reliably.

Answer (score 15):

You can also unload and reload the project also.  That's what works for me.

Comment: Works in 2013, and a much better solution for my situation where I have ~110 projects, so a Clean or a solution close/open takes forever... This is nice and fast if I only have 1 or 2 projects with stale errors.

Comment: Thanks! this works for VS2015
I could not get rid of the errors in a few projects, CleanSolution,Rebuild, nothing worked, the errors remained, but unloading & reloading each project worked like a charm

Comment: For VS2019 this didn't work for me... I had some C# syntax errors which were fixed (everything built) but unloading/reloading left them there.

Comment: I had some errors in VS2022 that this did actually fix. Part of the cause may have been TFS not letting files to change properly due to not checking Project Files out when I made changes and just exemplifying why TFS is awful.

Answer (score 10):

On the error list window in VS2015 there's a drop down that defaults to `Build + IntelliSense` switching this to `Build Only` fixed my issues (opening dlls via resharper and VS going crazy over it)

Answer (score 3):

I'm in VS 2013, writing reports.  I tried all the above steps (Clean Solution/Close solution/Reopen Solution).  Still had 3 errors in there 2 of which were from a 2 other reports that were not even opened.  The steps above didn't work.

What I had to do was redo those steps AND close VS 2013 & reopen it.  THAT fixed it.  One would think by simply closing/reopening the solution, it would fix it.  But restarting VS was the only way to fix it for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you work with multiple projects in one solution in VS2012, a filter by current project works well. You select your project in solution explorer and you get the list with the errors that belong to the selected project only.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Vs2022 64 bit Version 17.1.4.
My current project is a Winforms app and had an error that was pointing to a line that no longer existed!
No rebuild, clean would work, only unloading/reloading or restart visual studio fixed it.

Comment: Same thing here with VS2022 (last version) and a MVC / Blazor projects. Even closing the solution doesn't clear the error window.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with speechlib and I had to go back into the assembly and un-check "Microsoft Speech Object Library," and re-check it to clear 59 errors when I ran my Debug again. This method proved successful. I closed out Visual Studios and restarted it & that didn't work, nor did "clean solution." To answer your question, would depend on the situation however. As far as assemblies go, just remove them and then re-add them.

Answer (score 0):

I have VS 17, with a Python project.  With Python, there is no Build or Clean.  Closing the solution leaves the unwanted stuff in the ErrorList window, and reopening it doesn't change it.  I get my errors from running MyPy.  The unwanted stuff has the Project field blank, which I guess is why it isn't affected by new content associated with my project.
What I had to do to clear it was exit Visual Studio altogether and relaunch it.

Answer (score -1):

An old thread -
VS 2022 refreshes the error list on Rebuild All.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I can confirm that is not true as of 17.4 Preview 2.1... It usually does but after checking out a previous commit (detached) I have errors that will not clear (solution builds fine).  Also tried Unload and reload projects with error, that didn't work either.  The only thing that worked was close solution and reopen it (did not require restarting VS).

Comment: Doesn't work for me on VS 2022 17.4.1.